# Use ranges in if statements

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

In my sheet I have 2 seperate rows for example, and I want to compare them to eachother. If i wanted to do it the long way this is what it would look like:

```
=IF(AND(A1>B1, A2>B2 ect), "true", "false")
```

I want to be able to do it in a range like this:

```
=IF(A1:A50>B1:50, "true", "false")
```

What is a simple way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to compare here? If the total of `A1:A50` is greater than the total of `B1:B50` ?

Comment: Each individual value. Look in the first example. It to say true if a1> b1, and if a2 > b2 ect

Answer (score 0):

Does that help ?

```
=ArrayFormula(A1:A50>B1:B50)
```

Or, if you want a single output (TRUE if all of A1:A50 > B1:B50), try

```
=countif(ArrayFormula(A2:A50>B2:B50), "FALSE")=0
```

or,

```
=countif(ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A50)*len(B2:B50), if(A2:A50>B2:B50, true, false),)), false)=0
```

Comment: No, I just want a singular value. If one of the values is false then it outputs false

Comment: I believe you misunderstood what I asked(just realised.) I don't want it to compare everything to everything. I only want it to compare a1 to a2, b1 to b2, c1 to c3, ect. I just don't want to have to do this for hundreads of numbers

Comment: A1 to A2 or A1 to B1 as stated in your original post? As player0 already asked, can you share a copy of your spreadsheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12wQKqAHcaKWIRVGhz5Lr2wjJzOlZcNRtBdEtTJJY3WU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try one of these:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A50 > B1:B50, "true", "false"))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A50 > B1:B50, true, false))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A50 > B1:B50, true))
```

### ___________________________________________________________

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C1:C), IF(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A1:A>=C1:H, , 1)),,999^99)))="", "true", "false"), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This almost works, except more then one have to be false for it to say false

Comment: I just want a single output, not the 100 or so that one gives me for a bigger range

Comment: pls shere a copy of your sheet (or dummy with fake data) with example of desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12wQKqAHcaKWIRVGhz5Lr2wjJzOlZcNRtBdEtTJJY3WU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The new solution doesn't work for me. For example from the screenshot i would want it to compare a2 to c1, then a3 to d1 ect. What you have right now compares c2:h2 to a2, then c3:h3 to a3